# xpath - get first 10 items of selected set

Tags: xml, xpath, position

xml again..

I want to select a sub set of nodes ( for pagination purposes ) from a set.

```
$nodes = $xml->query(//parent
                        /child[sex = 'male' 
                               and position() >= 10 
                               and position() < 21]);
```

If I'm not mistaken that would only select male children who are the 10th to 20th child.

what I need is to select the first 10-20 (or 30-40) males in the set...

sure I'm being a noob and have done this before but its friday...

ta peeps

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation of the problem and a simple and short solution with step-by-step explanation. :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Have the position condition operate on the result nodeset of your initial condition:

```
//parent/child[sex='male'][position() >= 10 and position() < 21]
```

Comment: Jeebuzz - sorry for darkening your door... knew it was simples. tvm

Answer (score 6):

> I want to select a sub set of nodes (
>   for pagination purposes ) from a set.
>
> ```
> $nodes = $xml->query(//parent
>                          /child[sex = 'male'
>                                  and position() >= 10
>                                  and position() < 21]);
> ```
>
> If I'm not mistaken that would only
>   select male children who are the 10th
>   to 20th child.
>
> what I need is to select the first
>   10-20 (or 30-40) males in the set...

**You *are* mistaken**...

```
//parent/child
           [sex = 'male'
          and 
           position() >= 10
          and 
           position() < 21
           ]
```

Selects all `child` elements (of any `parent` element in the XML document) that have a `sex` child with sting value `"male"` and that are one of the 10th to 20th `child` children of their parent.

There could be only a few, or even none such elements.

**What you want is**:

1. Selects all `child` elements (of any `parent` element in the XML document) that have a `sex` child with sting value `"male"`
2. From the ones selected in step 1 above select only those in position 10 to 20

**So, for step 1**:

```
//parent/child[sex = 'male']
```

**and adding step 2**:

```
//parent/child[sex = 'male']
                [position() >= 10
               and 
                not(position() > 20
                ]
```